Two Sample Z-Test on Pandas dataframe
I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this.It is a frequency table.



landing_page
0
1




new_page
128045
17264


old_page
127785
17489



where 0 = not converted and 1 = converted.
I am trying to calculate a two sample Z-test to show if a new page affects conversion rate.
I am new to Python and I do not know how to use this dataframe to conduct the test.
Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks a lot.

Not sure what the numbers are, but you need the mean and the standard deviation to compute a Z-test. It looks like you're missing those

This is based on count. It is a frequency table.

So what would be the expected output? I don't see how you could compute a Z-score with only this aggregated data

stat, p_value = proportions_ztest(count=[17489, 17264], nobs=[17489 + 127785, 17264 + 128045], alternative='two-sided')
print(stat, p_value)

OK, got it, then you can pass the column and the sum

Following your comment, if you want to use proportions_ztest:
from statsmodels.stats.proportion import proportions_ztest

# ensure correct order (old -> new)
tmp = df.set_index(['landing_page']).loc[['old_page', 'new_page']]

# compute the score/p-value
stat, p_value = proportions_ztest(count=tmp[1], nobs=tmp[[0, 1]].sum(axis=1),
                                  alternative='two-sided')

Output:
# stat
1.3102408579271012

# p_value
0.19011436776805024


import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from statsmodels.stats.proportion import proportions_ztest

# Sample DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'landing_page': ['new_page', 'old_page'],
    'not_converted': [128045, 127785],
    'converted': [17264, 17489]
})

# Calculate totals
df['total'] = df['not_converted'] + df['converted']
'''
  landing_page  not_converted  converted   total
0     new_page         128045      17264  145309
1     old_page         127785      17489  145274
'''
convert_old = df.loc[df['landing_page' ] == 'old_page','converted'].values[0]
convert_new = df.loc[df['landing_page' ] == 'new_page','converted'].values[0]

total_old = df.loc[df['landing_page' ] == 'old_page','total'].values[0]
total_new = df.loc[df['landing_page' ] == 'new_page','total'].values[0]

count = np.array([convert_old,convert_new])
nobs =  np.array([total_old,total_new])

# Conduct the two-sample Z-test
z_statistic,p_value = proportions_ztest(count, nobs,alternative = 'two-sided')

print("Z-statistic:", z_statistic)#1.3102408579271012 
print("p-value:", p_value)#0.19011436776805024

